# how to get aggs count/buctuks from Flux<AggregationContainer>

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying the Elasticsearch aggregations in spring webflux.

I what to know how to get the buckets values (inside buckets count) from  Flux<AggregationContainer<?>> in Java API and total records in elasticsearch.

```
Request:
order/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
          "aggs": {  "status":
 { "terms": 
 { "field":"order_status" , "size": 100}}}}

Response:
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    .....
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "status" : {
    
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "CREATED",
          "doc_count" : 34
        },
        .....
        {
          "key" : "CANCELLED",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "COMPLETED",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Java imp:
  @Autowired
    private ReactiveElasticsearchOperations operations;
Flux<AggregationContainer<?>> result = operations.aggregate(searchQuery, Count.class, "indexs");
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When processing the `result` you have to parse what is returned in the `AggregationContainer` The type that is contained there comes from the Elasticsearch client library, so you need to check what properties it has. Spring Data Elasticsearch doe not do any parsing of aggregation results.